# Firebase Connectivity Test Shows Disconnected At Start Even When Connected. How Do I Change This?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make sure Firebase has a connection before continuing to load the app. I'm using the code from Firebase's own code sample. I have placed it in the ViewDidLoad function on my home view controller:

```
let connectedRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: ".info/connected")
    connectedRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if let connected = snapshot.value as? Bool, connected {
            print("Connected")
        } else {
            print("Not connected")
            // show alert here
        }
    })
```

The problem is that the above code always shows "Not Connected" before then showing "Connected". This is a problem because when the app is not connected, it's supposed to show an alert, and the alert will then fire every time the user opens the app.

Is this expected behavior? If so, is there a way around it?

How do I check for Firebase connectivity without Firebase returning that it's not connected first every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're observing is expected.  The Firebase SDK can't establish its connection immediately upon startup.  There is always going to be some latency between launch and whenever a connection is first available.

Also, I don't think this strategy is a good idea, because mobile connections can be intermittent and flakey.  Firebase can not possibly ensure that your app will retain a good connection even after it's first established.  Your app will be easier to use if you assume that it doesn't have a connection all the time.  Users have come to expect some level of offline usage, and Realtime Database supports that to some degree with [offline data persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities).

Comment: I see your point. I looked into using some sort of Reachability code, but it was quite complex and involved, and using Firebase's "quick check" code above seemed to be a simple solution. I do have offline persistence enabled for the app, but I was hoping to ensure a connection for at least some point in the session when the user launches.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a way to simply delay the response so that it has time to connect, and then send the response? I tried using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1`, but it didn't make a difference. Plus, I didn't know where to put that code anyway. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  Please consider asking another question with the code that you've tried and explain how it doesn't work the way you expect.